# 'Impressions' on Chrome Extension Stats stopped working since May 15

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know why 'Impressions' in the extension stats section, which is inside the developer dashboard on Google Chrome, stopped working since May 15th? I couldn't really find anything written about it.

Comment: Same problem, good to know that Google Analytics for market works fine.

Comment: Me too, anybody knows something?

Comment: Same for me!  
I found this [topic](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/XtdCeAT9bfw) that is four years old.  
Looks like shit happens time to time...

Comment: My numbers came back yesterday. I suppose it was related to the virus activities last week.